# Chromecast status code 2100 / Fails with local server

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm using a local server on my Android device to cast images + mp4s to Chromecast.

(I tried both - NanoHttpD and AndroidAsyncHttpServer) https://github.com/MikeMitterer/android-cromecastsample/tree/master/src/main/java/at/mikemitterer/mobile/chromecastsample/cast (GH-Repo)) but if I server the files from one of these local servers I get `Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 2100, resolution=null}`

Serving the files from an external server works - at least with a MP4-File.

This is the the server I'm currently using: https://github.com/MikeMitterer/android-cromecastsample/blob/master/src/main/java/at/mikemitterer/mobile/chromecastsample/cast/CastAsyncFileServer.java

The Activity that initializes everything: https://github.com/MikeMitterer/android-cromecastsample/blob/master/src/main/java/at/mikemitterer/mobile/chromecastsample/ui/MainActivity.java

and my buildMediaInfo-function: https://github.com/MikeMitterer/android-cromecastsample/blob/master/src/main/java/at/mikemitterer/mobile/chromecastsample/ui/MainActivity.java#L317-L341

This shows how the sample app looks like: [image: Screenshot]

Clicking on one of the images triggers the loadRemoteMedia -> buildMediaInfo.

I'm using the Chromecast V1 (old) Device on a 22" Monitor (No Audio with HDMI to DVI Converter) Streaming with other Apps than mine works. Im using the sample-app ID (4F8B3483) for testing.

BTW: (my second problem) If I use my own registered ID Chromecast connects fine but automatically disconnects after approximately 20secs...

I'm a bit lost - please help!

[**Update**]
Thanks to @ Ali Naddaf I re-registered my Application!!! not the device! I changed from "Remote Display Receiver" to "Styled Media Receiver" waited ~15mins turned off/on Chromecast now debugging works and my second problem, that Chromecast automatically disconnected after ~20secs, is also solved. Cool!

If you check my SS you can see that my image is set as background for the video-tag. Is this the way it should work or I am doing something wrong?
[image]

Comment: Are you using Cast SDK v3?  What I would suggest to do is the following: print out in your log the URL that you are setting in MediaInfo and report that back here and also point a browser on, say, your laptop (on the same network) to that url and see if it can load your media or not. Once the answer to that is know, we can continue with the troubleshooting.

Comment: Yea, I'm using Cast V3, this is the URL http://192.168.0.197:8900/free-flight.jpg and it works if I open the Url from Chrome (on my Mac) 192.168.0.197 is the Android WIFI Address. Chromecast is on 192.168.0.86

Comment: This is what I get if I click on "free-flight.jpg": Cast - onSessionStarting
Cast - onSessionStarted
Show: free-flight.jpg
Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 2100, resolution=null} The Activity that produces the logs: https://github.com/MikeMitterer/android-cromecastsample/blob/master/src/main/java/at/mikemitterer/mobile/chromecastsample/ui/MainActivity.java

Comment: I suggest you address the issue with your registered receiver so you can debug the issue by looking at your receiver. You can just use a styled receiver, if you are not doing that already; that gives you the ability to look at the logs on the receiver side.

Comment: For my tests I used "Remote Display Receiver" because I thought its the easiest route to take - I was wrong. Now most things work as expected. Maybe you should point this out in your Cast documentation. I've updated my question - maybe you have an answer...

Comment: I think it is clear in the docs; where did you see in the docs that it was suggesting Remote Display Receiver for media playback? As to the other question, if you want to write your own custom receiver, you can also use an image tag i html and set the source of that to the image you receive. I am not clear from your question whether you are running into an issue with displaying an image or you were just curious?